# SpringMVC + Websocket + Chat Initial HttpHandshake Failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I am trying to Implement chat in my existing Spring MVC app.I am referring to these two links from github -

1. [Spring STOMP](https://github.com/viorelt/spring-stomp)
2. [Spring Websocket Portfolio](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio)

But it looks like the initial HttpHandhsake is failing when I try to connect through websocket.I have uploaded my source code here - [Server Code](https://github.com/vishalpawale/conchact-server).
Here is brief about source code.
Configuration classes are-

1. ConChactConfiguration
2. ConChactWebSocketConfig

Only ChatController deals with WebSocket & webapp/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp contains the client side js.I am using STOMP over Sock JS.

So please have a look at the code & suggest me the changes for making Chat work.Currently when I see at network tab, it looks like intial HttpHandshake is failing, since latency for switch protocol request is very high(It never returns).

**Edit**
ScreenShots from Network & Console Panel - 
[image: Network Panel Output][image: Console Panel Output]

Answer (score 9):

Your linked code is fairly large, so it's hard to isolate where everything is happening... but here's a few things I had to deal with when I was getting the WebSocket stuff working with Spring:

(As a side note, I originally had a problem similar to yours where the initial handshake would fail with various error messages)

### Make sure you're using the latest Spring 4

These are the specific spring dependencies I'm using. From your pom, it looks like you're good here, but I'm including them in the list for reference (these are Gradle dependency declarations).

```
compile "org.springframework:spring-websocket:4.0.1.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.0.1.RELEASE"
```

### Make sure you're using the servlet 3.0 spec

web.xml should declare the servlet spec version as 3.0, not 2.3. It looks like you're using 2.3.

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

Not sure if this is a strict requirement, but I had to switch to get mine working. Here's the documentation reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html. I also had to add the "async-supported" element to all **servlet** definitions and **filter** definitions:

```
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

Also, you need to use a **compatible servlet container**. I had to upgrade to Tomcat 7.0.50 (I think the minimum is 7.0.47). The Spring documentation lists other compatible containers.

### Setup the server stuff correctly

Here's my Spring XML config:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/rt">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/endpoint" >
        <websocket:sockjs />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

So, I've made a topic at the endpoint "endpoint". The "application-destination-prefix" is not really being used AFAICT because I'm only pushing from server to client.

And then, not that it's necessarily relevant to your "can't connect" issue, but here's how I send messages to the topic:

```
SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingtemplate;
@Autowired
public void setSimpMessagingTemplate(SimpMessagingTemplate template){
    simpMessagingtemplate = template;
}

@Override
public void sendMessage(UserDetails userDetails, String message, DateTime time) {
    // Send notifications based on subscriptions
    for(String destUser : ...list of users...){
        this.simpMessagingtemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
            destUser,
            "/topic/notifications", 
            new MessagePayload(... Your stuff here...));
    }
}
```

### Setup the client stuff correctly

I'm using AngularJS, so this stuff is in a message service.

```
var socket = new SockJS('https://localhost:8443/WildFire/endpoint');
var stompClient  = Stomp.over(socket);

stompClient.connect('empty', 'empty', function(frame){
    $log.info("Connected");
    stompClient.subscribe('/user/topic/notifications', function(message){
        addMessage(JSON.parse(message.body));
    });
});
```

I needed to reference the complete URL of the websocket because SockJS wasn't working with a relative path to the endpoint. It was causing weird errors until I made that change. I'm doing a user-specific topic subscription, hence the "/user/..." in the subscribe declaration.

Also, I had to provide dummy credentials for the initial stompClient connect (eg. 'empty/empty'), otherwise I would get an error about lack of credentials. I think that using empty strings ('','') works as well.

### Setup spring security

It looks like in your security setup, your '/chat' URL falls under the blanket 'permitAll' condition. That shouldn't cause an issue, but you can secure the websocket endpoint the same as any other URL since it's all starting as a basic servlet request handled by Spring.

My security config handles the websocket endpoint as requiring an authenticated session and HTTPS, which works fine with the websockets and messaging systems. Because the websocket connection starts as a servlet request, it is authenticated the same as any other using the JSESSIONID established during the initial login.

Anyways, I'm not sure exactly sure what's causing your specific problem, but this is the process I went through to get my app working. It looks like you're doing something very similar to what I was doing, so hopefully this will help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks Dude.It's a very good answer, deserves up-vote.I tried all the suggestions you gave, but didn't got it working.I am going to edit my question with screenshots, please have a look to get better idea.Also I will try with creating new MVC project, I am just started to think that maybe my existing WebConfiguration is creating problems in configuring WebSocketConfiguration.

Comment: If you look at network panel the switching protocol request remained in pending state.And It falls back & start to try with other protocols like xhr_streaming & xhr but they also get failed.